# Overlaping dates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

```
ID  START DATE  END DATE
5194    2019-05-15  2019-05-31
5193    2017-02-08  2017-04-02
5193    2017-02-15  2017-04-10
5193    2021-04-01  2021-05-15
5191    2020-10-01  2020-11-20
5191    2019-02-28  2019-04-20
5188    2018-10-01  2018-11-30
```

i have a dataframe(this is just a part of it) , When the id value of the previous row equals the id value of the next row, i want to check if the dates of the 2 rows overlap, and if so i want to create a new row that keeps the longest date and drops the old ones, ie when the ID is 5193 i want my new row to be ID: 5193, START DATE: 2017-02-08 , END DATE: 2017-04-10 !!

Is that even doable? , tried to approach it with midle point of a date but didnt get any results! Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by longest date?

Comment: the furthest date, for the example it is from 02-08 till 04-10, and not 04-02

Comment: how it could be 04-10 it should be 05-15 ? Please post your expected output

Comment: i wrote it in the description, when the dates overlap each other for example , 2017-02-08 until 2017-04-02 gets overlaped by the next row, which is 2017-02-15 until 2017-04-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `agg`

```
import pandas as pd
a = """5194    2019-05-15  2019-05-31
5193    2017-02-08  2017-04-02
5193    2017-02-15  2017-04-10
5193    2021-04-01  2021-05-15
5191    2020-10-01  2020-11-20
5191    2019-02-28  2019-04-20
5188    2018-10-01  2018-11-30
"""
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split() for i in a.splitlines()], columns=["ID", "START DATE", "END DATE"])
df = df.assign(part_start_date=lambda x: x["START DATE"].astype(str).str[:7]).groupby(["ID", "part_start_date"]).agg({"START DATE": "min", "END DATE": "max"}).reset_index().drop("part_start_date", axis=1)


# output. Longest Date will be where start date is min and end_date is max
    ID  START DATE  END DATE
0   5188    2018-10-01  2018-11-30
1   5191    2019-02-28  2019-04-20
2   5191    2020-10-01  2020-11-20
3   5193    2017-02-08  2017-04-10
4   5193    2021-04-01  2021-05-15
5   5194    2019-05-15  2019-05-31
```

Comment: on your example it takes the row 3 as well, but the 3rd row doesnt overlap the other 2 so we dont want to change it

Comment: Do you want to overlap on day month only not year?

Comment: yes, exactly! thank you for this! maybe you could recommend a source that i could practise on problems like that?

Comment: there are lot of online platforms where you can learn. If you like the solution then plz upvote and accept it.